# Amortised analysis of binary heap insert and delete-min

Tags: algorithm-analysis, data-structures, runtime-analysis, heaps, amortized-analysis

I'm trying to figure out how to do amortised analysis of heap insert and heap delete-min using potential function.

We can assume, that insert is *O(logn)* and delete-min is *O(logn)* too.

The goal is to prove, that amortised price of insert is *O(logn)* and amortised price of delete-min is *O(1)*.

Can't figure out how to create a potential function.

```
POT.F = ?
INSERT c = logn + (something from 0 to xlogn)
DELETE-MIN c = logn + (something like -logn)
```

Could you guys help me? I've figure out so far that difference between potentials should be from *0* to *xlogn* so INSERT price would be *logn* and for *DELETE-MIN*, difference should be somewhere abour *-logn* to get constant price.

Comment: What kind of sequence of operations do you want to amortize over?

Comment: @raphael - any possible sequence of these two operations. So you can't delete-min if you did not push before etc.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. How to amortize for sequences with only one delete-min? Do you want to *average* over all sequences?

Comment: For example for operations PUSH and POP,  we can  say that their amortised price is PUSH = 2 POP = 0. If Pot. Function is size of stack, then PUSH = 1 + S+1 - S = 2 and POP = 1 + S-1 - S = 0. I mean it in this way.

Comment: No, you can't just "say" an operation has some amortized cost without fixing which kind of sequences you want to talk about. The amortized costs are the *end result*. It's really about the *total cost* of this sequence, which you may then divide by the number of operations to get "amortized costs" for single operations. Without a sequence, there's no total, and nothing to divide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, for a bit of clarifying terminology:  rather than proving an amortized insertion cost of $O(\lg n)$ and an amortized deletion cost of $O(1)$, you are using those amortized costs to prove something about the total cost of a sequence of insertions and deletions, starting with an empty heap.  This might be a subtle distinction, but it is fairly important (at least to me).  If you allow yourself to start from a non-empty heap, you would also need to allow yourself to start with a $\Theta(n \lg n)$ potential, or else the deletion amortized cost won't work.  Or, if you were to add in an operation for the worst-case linear time build-heap operation, you would also need for that linear time operation to add $\Theta(n \lg n)$ to the potential function.

To use your desired amortized runtimes, each insertion has to prepay for a deletion to come later.  So, for instance, when inserting into a heap of size $n$, you can pay for the actual insertion $O(\lg n)$, but your amortized cost will pay that plus an additional $O(\lg n)$ for the worst-case runtime of deleting from a heap of size $n+1$.  Now, every time you delete from a non-empty heap?  That deletion's actual cost has already been prepayed by a previous insertion's amortized cost.  It costs 0 (amortized) to delete.  The only deletions that you still need to pay for are the ones from an empty heap, for when your deletions outnumber prior insertions, and those cost $O(1)$.

While these bounds are fine to use for a proof of efficiency for a sequence of insertions and deletions, they are slightly odd, in that in real life, the deletions generally take expected $\Theta(\lg n)$ time, and insertions take expected $\Theta(1)$ time, for some reasonable definitions of operating on a random heap of size $n$.

While I have presented this in terms of "prepaying" (or the accounting method), in this case, just writing it down as a more formal equation directly transforms it into the potential function method.  You will be able to prove that the potential of a heap with $n$ elements is at least $\sum_{i=1}^n f(i)$ where $f(i)$ is the worst-case price to delete the min item from a heap if $i$ elements.  You already start your question with a given $O(\lg i)$ bound on $f(i)$.